# Can't figure out how to pass SQL results (single field value) to update another field in a different table

Tags: sql, vba

I think I have a very simple question that I can’t answer.  I have two tables: `tblAVAILABLE` and `tblWORKING`.

`tblAVAILABLE` has three fields:

- `fFILE`
- `fSHIFT`
- `fSENIORITY`

`tblWORKING` has two fields:

- `fSPOT`
- `fFILLEDBY`

The fields `tblAVAILABLE.fFILE` and `tblWORKING.fSPOT` are both unique

I have SQL that will query the `tblAVAILABLE` table to find the most senior person available for the shift.  I can get that to work.

I need to pass the field `tblAVAILABLE.fFILE` to a string so I can update the `tblWORKING.fFILLEDBY`field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query to do this.

```
UPDATE tblWORKING
SET fFILLEDBY = (/* YOUR FIND MOST SENIOR PERSON QUERY */)
WHERE fSPOT = /* WHATEVER */;
```

Just make sure your sub query is only returning 1 value and only 1 value.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I put it into my code I keep getting a compile error that my sub or function isn't defined.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've used? Sub queries can be tricky, as they should only return 1 cell 1 value. Perhaps you just have a slight syntax issue.

Comment: I've coded in VBA for Excel quite a bit.  Never in Access.  Sorry if I'm missing the basics here.  I appreciate your help.  If my experiences in Access are like they were in Excel, I'll start to get the hang of things.

Comment: Option Compare Database

Sub InserttoTable()
Dim Db As Database, qry As QueryDef
Dim strSql As String, tbl As TableDef, MyCopyToTable As TableDef
Dim rs As Recordset
Set Db = CurrentDb
 

strSql = " SELECT TOP 1 Object_Name FROM QbjectDetail WHERE Object_Type = 'Metric'  ORDER BY Object_Name; "

Update MyCopyToTable
Set fFILLEDBY = (strSql)
WHERE fSPOT = 19193


End Sub

Comment: I noticed you have an order by in your sub query there. You shouldn't need it. As I said, the sub query needs to return only 1 column 1 row, like literally just return 1 thing. Think of it this way, your sub query is in place of a value to compare, like SET x = (sub) -> SET x = y. If you have an order by I reckon you're trying to return a list of values.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you had a TOP 1 filter in your sub query. Perhaps that is not the issue then. I'm not a VBA guy myself so if there's a non-SQL issue here I wouldn't be of much help.

Comment: After I ORDER the results I pull only one field with SELECT TOP 1.  But I think that is the least of my problems since I can't even get the code to compile.

Comment: Just saw your last comment.  OK, thanks for your help.  My SQL issues are minor, it's getting it to work with VBA that is my issue.

Comment: Well, hopefully someone else with some VBA excel experience sees this post. Might I suggest editing your original post with the VBA code properly formatted?